# How to make neofetch run instantly?

Tags: linux, linux-terminal

I decided to make *Neofetch* run whenever I open a terminal window by editing `~/.bashrc` to execute it. However, there is a delay while printing out the system information and it takes a little bit of time until I can start using the terminal. I checked the config and parameters but I couldn't find anything to print it out instantly. Is this intentional or does it actually take that long to retrieve the system info? And if it can't be changed is there a better alternative that does have instant printing?

Answer (score 2):

Add it to bashrc file and it will run each time when you will open a terminal. But yes it consumes some time to get the information about the system. You can try this solution: https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/issues/1298

The second solution is here: https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/ep2jue/why_is_neoftech_slow/

Comment: Actually I found an alternative called paleofetch its basically the same thing but written in C and it prints out instantly too which is nice https://github.com/sam-barr/paleofetch/

Comment: Thanks for the clue. There are also pfetch and ufetch

Comment: people searching for a windows alternative may use macchina https://github.com/Macchina-CLI/macchina